# Using Drupal for an accounting system?

Tags: drupal, accounting

I'm working for non-profit whose has a very outdated system for tracking donations from its benefactors based on Microsoft Access 2003. They want to move to a web product (it's only used in-house), but I am very hesitant to build a lot from scratch. A technical consultant suggested using Drupal to replace the system, by building around it. I am unsure of this however, as Drupal seems mostly to be for content display only and not ideal for any sort of mathematical operation (such as summing the donations received in a year), reports, etc.

Does anyone have any experience using Drupal in this or a similar maner?

Comment: Hi. I'm also working for a non-profit and just developed our new Customer relationship management system to replace the outdated one (based on.. Excel :'( ) and I'm actually quite surprised (in the good way) of the result I get with D7. I guess that nothing is impossible and I hardly suggest you to investigate in this way. I also think that the mathematical operations shouldn't be a problem. If custom modules don't exist, there always are php functions that allow you do make very precise calculations (imo).

Answer (score 1):

Drupal is very flexible and there are a lot of powerful modules for (almost) anything.
I don't know your requirements, but I will recommend you give a try to this CMS. If your question is about how manipulate maths operation, look https://drupal.org/project/computed_field
But I think your solution can be near to CRM Core module: https://drupal.org/project/crm_core with https://drupal.org/project/crm_core_donation